# Fitting button and textview in multiple screen

Tags: android, layout, screen

I have encountered this problem, the TextView and the Buttons are not fitting to the size of the screen. I create the layout for 7in WSVGA, and when I tried to compile it on my tab, the appearance on it is not same as the design that I create, and then I tried to compile at SGS4, and the same is happened, the buttons and the textview. I have tried to add this code to my manifest.

```
<supports-screens 
android:resizeable="true"
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

this is the screenshot for the SGS4 [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZw1n.jpg), and for the tablet is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbCre.jpg).. 
Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/menulevel"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLevel1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnLevel6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/hitam1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLevel2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnLevel6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnLevel1"
    android:background="@drawable/hitam2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLevel3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnLevel2"
    android:background="@drawable/hitam3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLevel4"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnLevel3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnLevel8"
    android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hitam4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLevel6"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnLevel4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hitam6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLevel7"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnLevel5"
    android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hitam7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLevel8"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnLevel6"
    android:background="@drawable/hitam8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLevel5"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnLevel8"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnLevel2"
    android:background="@drawable/hitam5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/teksTotalSkor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/kosong"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But there is still not fitting on the screen of my tab and SGS4. are there any solutions?

Comment: (1) Post your XML in which you define theSe buttons, text views etc. (2) Upload the picture to http://imgur.com/ and paste a link in the question

Comment: those are the appearances on SGS4 and my tablet, and the XML. :D

Comment: How should it look when everything is correct? What do you mean by _"still not fitting on the screen"_

Comment: add a different layout and drawable for each screen size

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following xml code part instead of your score textview.

```
 <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/score_panel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/teksTotalSkor"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/kosong"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:textSize="40sp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:typeface="serif" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create folder **layout-sw600dp** and **layout-sw600dp-land** for 7 inch tablets(portrait and landscape)
Paste your layout in this folder then arrange the widgets accordingly.

when you will run your app on 7 inch device, layouts will be inflated from these folders